# How to toggle back table to where it only shows 4 rows - jQuery

Tags: jquery, foreach

I have a table set up to where it only shows 8 rows, and when a user clicks on a icon, it shows ALL the rows in a table.

What I am having trouble figuring out is how to toggle it back to its previous state to where it only shows 8 rows when the table is already toggled

```js
  $("#last-game-table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 8).show();
  $("#show-all").on("click", function() {
    $("tbody > tr", $(this).prev()).show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="last-game-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Gamertag</th>
      <th>Total Kills</th>
      <th>Total Deaths</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($lastWarzoneGameResults as $last)
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #36c; color: white;">{{ $last['gamertag'] }}</td>
      <td style="background-color: #36c; color: white;">{{ $last['totalKills'] }}</td>
      <td style="background-color: #36c; color: white;">{{ $last['totalDeaths'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="show-all" class="text-center">
  <a href="#!">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use classes, toggle them as needed and define the display stuff in CSS.

That gives you a lot more control over the process including the fact that you still have all your style definitions in CSS and not splattered all over your javascript.

Granted, your javascript in this case is 4 lines of code, but I'd still recommend using classes since every project can grow

Here's how your solution would like using my approach (notice how I managed to add an extra gimmick without any additional javascript):

```js
$("#last-game-table > tbody > tr").addClass('toggle').slice(0, 4).removeClass('toggle');
$("#show-all").on("click", function() {
  $('#last-game-table').toggleClass('show-all');
});
```

```css
#last-game-table > tbody > tr.toggle {
  display: none;
}
#last-game-table.show-all > tbody > tr {
  display: table-row;
}
#show-all i.fa {
  transition: transform .5s;
}
.show-all + #show-all i.fa {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#last-game-table > tbody td {
  background-color: #36c; color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="last-game-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Gamertag</th>
      <th>Total Kills</th>
      <th>Total Deaths</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test 1</td>
      <td>foo 1</td>
      <td>bar 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 2</td>
      <td>foo 2</td>
      <td>bar 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 3</td>
      <td>foo 3</td>
      <td>bar 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 4</td>
      <td>foo 4</td>
      <td>bar 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test 5</td>
      <td>foo 5</td>
      <td>bar 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="show-all" class="text-center">
  <a href="#!">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not also put the  `style="background-color: #36c; color: white;"` in the style sheet/css

Comment: good point @MarkSchultheiss I just copied that from the question without even thinking about it, I'll change it as soon as I can get get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `show-less` DIV to do it (change the class so you get an appropriate icon for this).

```
<div id="show-less" class="text-center">
    <a href="#!">
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Hide this in the initial CSS:

```
#show-less {
    display: none;
}
```

The `show-all` code hides its DIV and displays the `show-less` DIV.

```
$("#show-all").on("click", function() {
    $("#last-game-table tbody > tr").show();
    $(this).hide();
    $("#show-less").show();
});
$("#show-less").on("click", function() {
    $("#last-game-table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 8).show();
    $(this).hide();
    $("#show-all").show();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. This makes the table show all the rows, and the button is not working now on the first click, but is working on the second.

Comment: Where did you put the new button? It needs to be after the old button, because the old button uses `$(this).prev()` to find the table instead of using its ID.

Comment: I've changed my answer to use the table ID in both buttons.